# Laravel 5.2 CSRF Field on every form?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

well, my question of the day is:

I have a Laravel 5.2 project running with standard authentication. I'm logged in into my backend, everythings fine. But is it normal that I have to use on every form `{{ csrf_field() }}`.

I know I have it in the Login form and it is necessary.

But when I build a new form in my backend, Laravel wants "CSRF Verification" despite the fact, that my model, I will save my data to, has no `_token`-Field.

So I implemented the `{{ csrf_field() }}` and used `$match->bet()->create($request->except(['_token']));` in my controller to avoid errors.

Is this the right way? Seems odd to me.

Is it a normal behaviour of Laravel, that I have to use {{ csrf_field() }} on every form? Or is there a way to avoid that on POSTS? An easy way...

Comment: You wan't to disable csrf on certain post request right ?

Comment: Not clear what do you want to do... Can you clarify, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `Form::open()` it's automatically add csrf field to your form. And you don't need to use `csrf_token()` helper function.

To use `Form` facade you need install `laravelcollective` because `HTML` and `Form` were removed from Laravel 5.*
https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html

Comment: OK, I understand that, but with that field I have always '_token' in my Request variable, although I don't need it, because my models don't have that column.

Comment: You need it for security reason. You can specify `fillable` fields for each model and pass `$request->all()` to create\update method

Comment: I don't have and don't need in all my models the column "_token", but without it, it throws an error. So I have to use always `$match->bet()->create($request->except(['_token']));` to not use the "_token" in the REQUEST. IS that the right approach?

Answer (score 0):

You could just remove the CSRF middleware if you are that bothered by it. It is there to protect you. Though the better option would be to add exemptions to the VerifyCsrfToken middleware.

```
protected $except = [
    'admin/*'
];
```

If you want to exclude all URLs in 'admin' perhaps.

As xAoc mentioned setting 'fillable' correctly on a model should help filter out any unwanted fields when filling a model, as well.